# Postman send request shows empty json

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mern

Doing a send request to test connection to MongoDB results in empty object. I have looked around and think that my test.http is being seen as text and not json... but am using app.use(express.json()) for parsing so I am a little confused.

Any thoughts?

Files below:

index.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
const routesUrls = require('./routes/routes')
const cors = require('cors')

dotenv.config() 

mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_ACCESS, () => console.log("DB connected"))

app.use(express.json())
app.use(cors())
app.use('/app', routesUrls)
app.listen(4000, () => console.log("server is running"))
```

routes.js

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const newPlayersTemplateCopy = require('../models/newPlayers')


router.post('/newplayers', (request, response) =>{
    const newPlayers = new newPlayersTemplateCopy({
        playerA:request.body.playerA,
        playerB:request.body.playerB,
        playerC:request.body.playerC,
        playerD:request.body.playerD
    })
    newPlayers.save()
    .then(data =>{
        response.json(data)
        console.log("Send request successful")
    })
    .catch(error => {
        response.json(error)
        console.log("Send request failed")
    }) 
})

module.exports = router
```

newPlayers.js (model)

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')


const newPlayersTemplate = new mongoose.Schema ({
    playerA:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    playerB:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    playerC:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    playerD:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    date:{
        type:Date,
        default:Date.now
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('playertable', newPlayersTemplate )
```

test.http

```
POST http://localhost:4000/app/newplayers
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "playerA":"Goku",
    "playerB":"Chichi",
    "playerC":"Vegeta",
    "playerD":"Bulma"
}
```

Response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 2
ETag: W/"2-vyGp6PvFo4RvsFtPoIWeCReyIC8"
Date: Tue, 30 Nov 2021 22:54:58 GMT
Connection: close

{}
```

UPDATE, running console.log(newPlayers) and console.log("request body", JSON.stringify(request.body, null, 2)) outputs these objects:

```
console.log(newPlayers)

{
  playerA: 'Goku',
  playerB: 'Chichi',
  playerC: 'Vegeta',
  playerD: 'Bulma',
  _id: new ObjectId("61a7b964229ac0dd680909aa"),
  date: 2021-12-01T18:05:24.968Z
}


console.log("request body", JSON.stringify(request.body, null, 2))

request body {
  "playerA": "Goku",
  "playerB": "Chichi",
  "playerC": "Vegeta",
  "playerD": "Bulma"
}
```

UPDATE: here is my package.json incase it helps

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Game Tracker",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^6.0.14",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15"
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your postman request already using POST method?

Comment: @wisnuaryadipa i think so

Comment: Btw, can you screenshot your postman

Comment: Can you log the request body before trying to save the model? `console.log("request body", JSON.stringify(request.body, null, 2))`. That will let you know if the issue is in the request from Postman or in the saving to Mongo

Comment: [@Ilia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3392005/ilia) Have you tried to `console.log( newPlayers)` to check actually `req.body` getting body parameters or not?

Comment: You are missing the `app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))` middleware

Comment: @LucaPizzini OP is sending JSON requests. They do not need the `urlencoded` middleware

Comment: @Phil - it returns this : 
request body {
  "playerA": "Goku",
  "playerB": "Chichi",
  "playerC": "Vegeta",
  "playerD": "Bulma"
}

Comment: @SmitGajera - it reutrns this: {
  playerA: 'Goku',
  playerB: 'Chichi',
  playerC: 'Vegeta',
  playerD: 'Bulma',
  _id: new ObjectId("61a7b964229ac0dd680909aa"),
  date: 2021-12-01T18:05:24.968Z
}

Comment: @wisnuaryadipa - response is last batch of coded text in the description

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that you're actually getting an error but it doesn't serialise to JSON. Can you change your `catch` to use `response.status(500).send(error)` instead?

Comment: @Phil - response i get back is HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 2
ETag: W/"2-vyGp6PvFo4RvsFtPoIWeCReyIC8"
Date: Thu, 02 Dec 2021 12:05:03 GMT
Connection: close

{} ---the curly braces is where i would expect my players to show up

Answer (score -1):

I realised after trying phils suggestions in the comments that my send requests weren't reaching my mongoDB at all.

I hate to say this but the problem was that I was not connected even though...

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_ACCESS, () => console.log("DB connected"))
```

...console logged DB connected

I fixed my issue by updating my .env file with new DB user credentials with atlas role. A couple minutes later, I was able to successfully send a post request:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 149
ETag: W/"95-f4qcpD1sEqrKjD5m/F1I1ldl6w4"
Date: Thu, 02 Dec 2021 12:31:38 GMT
Connection: close

{
  "playerA": "Goku",
  "playerB": "Chichi",
  "playerC": "Vegeta",
  "playerD": "Bulma",
  "_id": "61a8bcaa16b91600c2a0a8f7",
  "date": "2021-12-02T12:31:38.288Z",
  "__v": 0
}
```